# Hangfire.Console with Redis does not seems to work

Tags: logging, redis, hangfire

I want to use Hangfire.Console with Redis, but it does not seems to work.

I have the following configuration code:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .UseRedisStorage(RedisMultiplexer)
    .UseConsole();
```

The JobMethod:

```
public void AddLatestDocsToIndex(PerformContext context)
{
    var lastId = this.GetIdsByIndexerConfiguration(this.IndexerConfigurations["GetLastDocIdFromIndex"]).FirstOrDefault();
    var models = TransactionEntityModel.GetBiggerThanId(lastId);
    if (!models.Any())
    {
        context.WriteLine("No new documents found.");
        return;
    }
    var helper = new SearchHelper<TransactionEntityConfiguration, TransactionEntityModel>();
    helper.AddOrUpdateBulk(models);
    context.WriteLine($"Added {models.Count} document(s) to the index.");
}
```

And the Hangfire recurring job call:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TransactionEntityConfiguration>(
    "TransactionLatestDocsIndexer",
    x => x.AddLatestDocsToIndex(null),              
    Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
```

In the dashboard I don't see any Logging message. Also, when I look in Redis, the log messages don't show up anywhere.

I am using the following packages and versions:

```
<package id="Hangfire" version="1.6.12" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Hangfire.Console" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Hangfire.Core" version="1.6.12" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange" version="1.6.7.24" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.